# Magento 2 error when run php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, production-mode, dicompilation

I am using magento 2.1.5 when i change developer to production mode got the error like this

Enabled maintenance mode

Starting compilation

Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.

Command returned non-zero exit code:

```
/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin/php -f /www/sites/hostname/files/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

so i running the following command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

got the error like below

```
[ReflectionException]                                       
  Class Magento\Braintree\Model\Config\PayPal does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced such issue once. Please check file/folder name, Its case sensitive and should be exact or possible permission issue.

Comment: I didn't change any folder name and file. what permission should i give to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try running setup:upgrade before setup:di:compile?

Comment: Please check Magento documentation for file permission. If you are on local the 777  can do But just on local not on production.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check and change

`/vendor/magento/module-braintree/Model/Paypal` to

```
/vendor/magento/module-braintree/Model/PayPal
```

Change the Upper case for PayPal.Then Compile it.

Comment: it didn't work for me. again got same error [ReflectionException]                                       
  Class Magento\Braintree\Model\Config\PayPal does not exist

Comment: Could you pleas check the vendor folder for shortcut.php in the Braintree module. since it was working with the lowest version of Magento. but in latest they removed it